# Unsupported hardware uses: Android TV app rejection

Tags: android, android-tv

We currently have an app in the Android that we're trying to add to the Android TV app store. It seems to be continually reject for what I believe is an ambiguous reason. You can see the screenshot below. The link given in the email points to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware#unsupported-features).

[image: App rejection email]

Our manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor" android:required="false"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:banner="@drawable/testfairybanner"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.testfairy.app.MobileMainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TvMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

    <service android:name=".AccountAuthenticatorService" android:exported="true" android:process=":auth">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
</application>
```

As far as I can tell, I've addressed all the requirements needed for Android TV, however, the app continues to get rejected. If anyone has had this problem and has fixed it, I'd really love to know how you got around it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about appstore policy are not about programming *per se*; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Add to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
```

If you look carefully this is actually mentioned on the [page](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware#unsupported-features) you were directed to. For some reason this line is missing from example provided on the same page.